# My Unpublished Firebase Project Has An Unknown User, Has My Project Been Hacked?

Tags: android, firebase, security, firebase-authentication, rules

I have a firebase project that hasn't been made public(via my Android app or otherwise).
Today I saw an unknown google user account in the Authentication page.
I have previously set up firebase security rules to limit access, but I don't know if there are rules to stop account creation from outside my app. Is my project compromised?